# Are the groups $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ isomorphic if they have the same order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ the set of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e the elements with multiplicative inverse). And consider the groups:
$$(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, (\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, (\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, (\mathbb{Z}/40\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, (\mathbb{Z}/48 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$$

Show that at least 2 are isomorphic. (Hint: Verify that they have the same order. It's not necessary to determine which two groups are isomorphic).

So, following the hint, I calculated the order of the groups and found that

$\vert (\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= 17, \vert (\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= 16, \vert (\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= 16, \vert (\mathbb{Z}/40\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= 15, \vert (\mathbb{Z}/48\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \vert= 8.$

Therefore, the candidates are $(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. However when looking at the elements, both of the groups are formed by the equivalence classes of odd numbers, but $(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ includes the class $\overline{17}$, while $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ doesn't have $\overline{17}$ but instead $\overline{33}$. Moreover, I know that the common equivalence classes won't have the same order since for the first, the classes are $\text{mod}(32)$ and for the second, they are $\text{mod}(34)$. So I discarded the idea of setting a map from each class in $(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ to the same one in $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, $\overline{17} \mapsto \overline{33}$ and showing it is a homomorphism.

So, my question is, from the hint it kinda looks like it is enought to show they have the same order to conclude they are isomorphic. But I don't see why and even more, I wouldn't know how to show that they are isomorphic without narrowing down the options to the two candidates.

Comment: You have not calculated the orders of these groups correctly – these groups all have order 16. Can you explain your thought process there so we can help?

Comment: Once you figure out what went wrong with finding the orders, hint: what are all the isomorphism classes of abelian groups of order 16? And, to answer the question in the title, not necessarily. For example $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times$ both have order $4$, but are not isomorphic.

Comment: Consider $n=8,m=5.$

Comment: Okay, I see the mistakes for $(\mathbb{Z}/17 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/40 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, it was that I counted the $0$ for the first and discarded the $40$ twice in the second. Now, for $(\mathbb{Z}/48 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ I counted how many relatively prime numbers they had, since $48=2*2*2*2*3$ that left all the odd numbers up to $47$ (24) minus the multiples of $3$ (16) but then again, I discarded twice those that are multiples of $6$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Okay, I tried to find the isomorphism classes as you suggested. I got $Z_{16}$, $Z_8\times Z_2$, $Z_4\times Z_4$, $Z_4\times Z_2 \times Z_2$ and $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$. I was expecting to be like...oh there are 4 isomorphism classes and there are 5 groups, so at least two of them are isomorphic. But I got 5 classes. Did I calculate the classes wrong? Can I discard one (or maybe more) ?

Comment: I can discard $Z_{16}$ since the unit sets are not cyclic groups (i.e not generated by a single element), right?

Comment: No, $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic. But we can show that none of these groups is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^4$ -- just find an element of order $>2$ in each!

Answer (score 1):

The given groups are $ U_{17}, U_{32}, U_{34}, U_{40} \, and \, U_{48} $ which are respectively isomorphic to
$\mathbb Z_{16}, \mathbb Z_ 2 \times \mathbb Z_8 , U_2 \times U_{17}, U_8\times U_5 \, and \, U_{16} \times U_3$. These are respectively isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{16}, \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_{16}, \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_4, \, and \, \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2 $. Hence the first and the third groups are isomorphic and also the fourth and fifth groups are also isomorphic. I have used the isomorphism theorems pertaining to the multiplicative groups "$ U_{pq} \, is \, isomorphic \, to \, U_p \times U_q $" when p and q are coprime and also results relating to converting multiplicative groups of orders with even power prime and odd power primes into product of cyclic groups.

Comment: There's a typo in the fourth group, which should be $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I have corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can see fairly directly that at least $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ are isomorphic.

Indeed, $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ are the set of integers
$\{k \in \{1,2, \ldots, 33\}$; $k$ odd;$ (k,17)=1\}$. So let $\phi$: $(\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \mapsto (\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$; be the following mapping:
$$\phi(k) = k \mod 17$$

Then $\phi$ is indeed an isomorphism. You can also check the following: $\phi^{-1}$: $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \mapsto (\mathbb{Z}/34\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$; is as follows: $\phi^{-1}(\ell)$
$=$ $\ell +17$ iff $\ell \in \{2,4,6,8, \ldots, 16\}$; $\phi^{-1}(\ell) = \ell$ iff $\ell \in \{1,3, \ldots, 15\}$.

In fact this trick can be extended to show
$(\mathbb{Z}/M\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2M\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for any odd $M \ge 3$.

However, already noted in the comments I believe, to answer the title question of this thread,$(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ has 8 squares whereas $(\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ has only at most 4, namely $k \equiv_8 1$, so even though they have the same order, they are not isomorphic.