# Show that $G_1$ and $G_3$ are not isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism

While practising for an exam I encountered the following question.

> Consider the groups $G_1=(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $G_2=(\mathbb{Z}/110\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $G_3=(\mathbb{Z}/132\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.
>
> (a) Show that these three groups have the same number of elements.
>
> (b) Show that $G_1$ and $G_3$ are not isomorphic.
>
> (c) Show that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic. (Hint:  probably the shortest way to do this, is to use both the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the theory of elementary divisors).

I know how to solve $(a)$, we use Euler's totient function and find that they all have 40 elements. However at $(b)$ I get stuck. I tried prime factorisation: $$100 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5\\
132 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 $$
Then by the chinese remainder theorem we find
$$G_{1}=(\mathbb{Z} / 100 \mathbb{Z})^{x} \cong  (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \\G_{3}=(\mathbb{Z} / 132 \mathbb{Z})^{x} \cong  (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z} / 11 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$$ Now here I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. I assume $(c)$ can be done in a similar way?

Comment: You have obviously shown that they're not isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \not \simeq \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \not \simeq \mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ or am I wrong?

Comment: The last two equations are wrong. Look at the order. Then $|G_1|=\phi(2)\phi(2)\phi(5)\phi(5)=1\cdot 1\cdot 4\cdot 4$, which is wrong.

Comment: We have $\phi(100)=\phi(132)$ but $\lambda(100)\ne\lambda(132)$. Therefore, $G_1$ and $G_3$ have different exponents and so cannot be isomorphic. Here $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: Yeah I already wondered how that could be correct as then they would have different order

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165335/are-the-groups-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-times-and-mathbbz-m-mathbbz), $13$ hours ago.

Comment: Your application of the CRT is incorrect. You seem to be claiming, among other things, that $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$. which is patently false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied the chinese remainder theorem incorrectly. Recall that if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ the chinese remainder theorem states that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/p_1^{\alpha_1}\mathbb Z \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z/p_k^{\alpha_k}\mathbb Z$ (and similarly for the multiplicative group).

Thus, we have $$(\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z)^* \cong (\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z)^* \times (\mathbb Z/25 \mathbb Z)^*.$$

Note that $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^*\cong C_2$ (where $C_n = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for brevity) and $(\mathbb Z/25 \mathbb Z)^* \cong C_{20}$, hence applying the chinese remainder theorem again we find $G_1 = (\mathbb Z/100 \mathbb Z)^* \cong C_2 \times C_{20} \cong C_2 \times C_4 \times C_5$.

Similarly, we have $G_2 = (\mathbb Z/110\mathbb Z)^* \cong (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^* \times (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^* \times (\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^* \cong C_4 \times C_{10} \cong C_4 \times C_2 \times C_5$

$G_3 = (\mathbb Z/132\mathbb Z)^* \cong (\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^* \times (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^* \times (\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^* \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{10} \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_5.$

It's then clear that $G_1 \cong G_2$, and showing that $G_1 \not\cong G_3$ should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the CRT, you can look at the Sylow-$2$ subgroups and show that $(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/110\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ have elements of order $4$:
$$43^4=3418801=34188\cdot100+1\\
23^4=279841=2544\cdot110+1$$
On the other hand, the Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/132\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ is elementary abelian, which can be seen by finding more than $4$ elements of order $2$:
$$1^2=1\\
23^2=529=4\cdot132+1\\
43^2=1849=14\cdot132+1\\
65^2=4225=32\cdot132+1\\
67^2=4489=34\cdot132+1\\
\text{...}$$
Now by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups, the first two groups are isomorphic, but the third one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

(b)

Isomorphic groups have the same order and the same [exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group). (But the converse is not true.)

$G_1$ and $G_3$ have the same order because $\phi(100)=\phi(132)$, but they have different exponents because $\lambda(100)\ne\lambda(132)$. Therefore, $G_1$ and $G_3$ cannot be isomorphic.

Here $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).